# Is there any hook or event I can capture when kodi cursor moves onto a video item?

Tags: kodi, xbmc

I am writing a kodi video plugin. The videos are grouped by categories. Now, when I open a category I get a (long) list of videos in the category. I would like to capture some additional info from the web (tmdb) in the moment, when a video entry gets the focus inside the video list and show that as video information (kodi named this plot for example).

I already tried loading the web information and adding this a plot to the video information (kodi item) during netering the category when the list is built. But this takes a long time if the list is long and kodi is blocked as long as the list is built and returned.

So I am looking for soemthing like item.gotFocus() or similar, that is fired by kodi when a video list item gets the focus. I would then like to load the information from the web and provide it to the UI.